# How to produce a table using backbone js where my <tr> class for odd and even row are different?

Tags: backbone.js

Below code is my backbone view. :

```
app.WorkerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    className: 'odd',
    template: _.template(templat1e),

    render: function() {
        //this.el is what we defined in tagName. use $el to get access to jQuery html() function
        window.alert("I am in render function of WorkerView");
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));

        return this;
    }
});
```

But this can produce html with  class odd only. My goal is to produce html with different class for odd and even row. What I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with backbone but if you are using template to render your html fragment then you may try this out

```
<% _each(list, function(index) { %>
    <tr <% if (index%2 == 0) { %>class="even" <% } else { %>class="odd" <% } %> ></tr>
<% }); %>
```